# Using Dispatch.main in code called from XCTestCase does not work

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a function that is a async wrapper around a synchronous function.

The synchronous function is like:

```
class Foo {
    class func bar() -> [Int] {
        return [1,2,3]
    }

    class func asyncBar(completion: @escaping ([Int]) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let intArray = bar()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(intArray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call it from a `XCTestCase` `completion` does not run.

Is there some sort of perverse interaction between the way unit tests are done in XCode and the main thread?

I can find no documentation on the Web about this.

I have to use the main thread for the callback as it interacts with the Gui.

My test case looks something like:

```
func testAsyncBar() throws {
    var run = true
    func stopThisThing(ints: [Int]) {
        run = false
    }
    Foo.asyncBar(completion: stopThisThing)
    while run {
        print ("Running...")
        usleep(100000)
    }
}
```

The busy loop at the end never stops.

Comment: You block the main thread by busy waiting, so your completion handler never gets a chance. This isn’t how you should test a sync code, for one it’s reallllly cpu intensive and will massively slow your tests. I can elaborate in the morning tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test’s `while` loop will block the main thread (if the test runs on the main thread). As such, the closure dispatched via `DispatchQueue.main.async` can never run, and your `run` Boolean will never get reset. This results in a deadlock. You can confirm this by printing `Thread.isMainThread` or adding a test like `dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))`.

Fortunately, unit tests have a simple mechanism that avoids this deadlock.
If you want unit test to wait for some asynchronous process, use an `XCTestExpectation`:

```swift
func testAsyncBar() throws {
    let e = expectation(description: "asyncBar")

    func stopThisThing(ints: [Int]) {
        e.fulfill()
    }

    Foo.asyncBar(completion: stopThisThing)

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5)
}
```

This avoids problems introduced by the `while` loop that otherwise blocked the thread.

See [Testing Asynchronous Operations with Expectations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations).

Comment: Yes, that works.  Thank you.  Only tangentially related to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations   and I can see no reason for it.  But it works.  I will have to seriously consider what it does to my testing as I cannot test the callbacks that I actually use!

Comment: The `while` loop (and dispatch semaphore and group `wait` calls) block the caller’s thread, and thus if you're waiting for something that will be set from a block dispatched to the same thread (the main queue in your example) you have a deadlock. The `waitForExpectations`, however, continues to let the run loop process events (including blocks dispatched to the main queue via GCD), avoiding this deadlock scenario.

Comment: No semaphores in my original code.  The `while` loop blocks nothing as the thread that the while loop is on has spawned another thread (hard to actually know with the `DispatchQueue` stuff.)

Comment: Lol. I know your code isn't using semaphores. It's not using dispatch groups either. I'm just saying that those are two techniques that accomplish the same thing as your `while` loop, but are more efficient. But all three approaches obviously block the thread on which the test is running. And tests generally run on the main thread. Check `print(Thread.isMainThread)` or `dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))`. So, if main thread is tied up spinning on your `while` loop, closure dispatched asynchronously with `DispatchQueue.main.async` will never run. Hence deadlock.

Comment: Right!  The test is running on the main thread, of course.  That makes sense.  Ny thinking was stuck on the Gui running on the main thread,...  and just silliness from that point.  Thank you

Comment: On reflection, although you have addressed how to run a test, the explanation that the main thread is busy is not true.  The call to `usleep` should not block the thread.

Comment: @Worik - No offense, but that just is not correct: A `usleep` _does_ block the thread. This is easily demonstrated. (Sure, when you sleep, the CPU core is free to switch to other threads, but make no mistake, the original thread _is_ blocked.) And this is why your question’s sample deadlocks. The key here is that `waitForExpectations`, unlike `while`-`usleep`, will allow the run loop to process events.